# splitting two letters to create a word python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that will ultimately decode words in a file that are in this format:

```
first letter, last letter
rest of word
```

Then the code will take those words and cross check them with a word list to determine which of the words is not an actual word. 
This is a homework assignment, but I am very new to python and could really use some help. So far, I've been able to open the coded message and get python to print all of the coded words, but I'm stuck on how to split the first and last letters and have them form a word with the rest of the letters in the line below. 
I started attacking this in small pieces, this is the code I've done so far:

```
    filef=open('coded_msg.txt')
    R=list(filef)
    for line in R:
        print(str.join("",(R)))
        break
```

That's the code that actually works. I've tried several other things but all of them result in various errors. I don't want it to be done for me, but any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Everything is working except this small part:
as described in my comment, the actual format of the first and last letter is as follows: ab
Python views this as one character instead of two, which means I can't split the letters using split because it returns an 'out of range' error.
since I can't figure out how to get python to recognize the two letters as separate characters, I'm trying to insert a comma between the two letters so the format will be: a,b
Here's my code:

```
 f=open("coded_msg.txt")
 y=f.read()
 for i, line in enumerate(y):
    if i%2==0:
        continue 
    else:
        print(",".join(y))
    break
```

but this puts a comma between every letter in every line. Why is the enumerate function not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve then here is some code to decode your message:

```
f = open('coded_msg.txt')
your_list_of_allowed_words=[] # Put your allowed words in this list
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i%2 == 0: # Lines with index 0,2,4,...are those with first letter, last letter
        letters=line.split(",")
    else: # Lines with index 1,3,5,... are those with rest of word
        word = "%s%s%s" % (letters[0].strip(), line.strip(), letters[1].strip())
        if word in your_list_of_allowed_words:
            print(word)
f.close()
```

A better version would use the fact that `f` is an iterator we can call [`next`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#next) on to advance it and get the next value, so we dont need the line numbers inside `for` but read two lines in every iteration.

```
f = open("coded_msg.txt")
your_list_of_allowed_words=[]
for line in f:
    letters=line.split(",")
    word = "%s%s%s" % (letters[0].strip(), next(f).strip(), letters[1].strip())
    if word in your_list_of_allowed_words:
        print(word)
f.close()
```

Comment: this was very helpful, but I messed up. the letters are not split by a comma in the text file, instead they show up like: gd

Comment: for example^. but python sees 'gd' as one thing rather than two separate things so when I try to split it using letters[0] and letters[1] it returns a 'out of range' error. How can i get python to see the two first letters as separate characters so i can split them?

Comment: If the two letters are not seperated by a special character then you need not (can not) split it but should get the whole line into a variable and access the two chracters by simple indexing. Instead of `letters=line.split(",")` do `letters=line`. `letters[0]` will then be the first character `letters[1]` the second.